# What is the difference between UIImage, CIImage and CGImage in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm confused with when to use UIImage, CIImage and CGImage

What is the difference between them? When can I use them?

Comment: Check https://medium.com/@ranleung/uiimage-vs-ciimage-vs-cgimage-3db9d8b83d94

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UIImage**

> Apple describes a UIImage object as a high-level way to display image
>   data. You can create images from files, from Quartz image objects, or
>   from raw image data you receive. They are immutable and must specify
>   an image’s properties at initialization time. This also means that
>   these image objects are safe to use from any thread. Typically you can
>   take NSData object containing a PNG or JPEG representation image and
>   convert it to a UIImage. To create a new UIImage, for example:

```
var newUIImage = UIImage(data: data)
//where data is a NSData
```

**CIImage**

> A CIImage is a immutable object that represents an image. It is not an
>   image. It only has the image data associated with it. It has all the
>   information necessary to produce an image. You typically use CIImage
>   objects in conjunction with other Core Image classes such as CIFilter,
>   CIContext, CIColor, and CIVector. You can create CIImage objects with
>   data supplied from variety of sources such as Quartz 2D images, Core
>   Videos image, etc. It is required to use the various GPU optimized
>   Core Image filters. They can also be converted to NSBitmapImageReps.
>   It can be based on the CPU or the GPU. To create a new CIImage,

for example:

```
var newCIImage = CIImage(image: image)
//where image is a UIImage
```

**CGImage**

> A CGImage can only represent bitmaps. Operations in CoreGraphics, such
>   as blend modes and masking require CGImageRefs. If you need to access
>   and change the actual bitmap data, you can use CGImage. It can also be
>   converted to NSBitmapImageReps. To create a new UIImage from a
>   CGImage,

for example:

```
var aNewUIImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
//where imageRef is a CGImage
```

Answer (score 0):

They belong to different frameworks: `UIKit`, `CoreImage` and `CoreGraphics` respectively.

Normally, you use `UIImage`, unless you have a specific use case where other frameworks come in handy (such as using `CoreImage` filters).